# Gears modeling in Google SketchUp and SketchyPhisics

Tags: design, mechanism, 3d-printing

I'm trying to make differential in Google SketchUp using this tutorial http://support.ponoko.com/entries/21249896-Gears-and-Joints-with-SketchUp-Sketchy-Physics for gears modeling.
But I have problem: gears don't collide with any objects (and other gears). What's wrong? How to fix this?
How to make a bevel gear placed at 90 degrees relative to each other and conical cylindrical gears joints?

P.S. Is there something like SketchUp and SketchyPhisics in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my personal experience, I hate Google SketchUp. I Recommend that you use CAD Solidworks. Google SketchUp is not meant for gear design. In Solidworks, you are able to create gears however you may and also make it function on a three-dimensional visual on your computer screen. *I personally recommend this to you with great honestly.